# Pandas groupby filter on column, and then plot the results

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, seaborn

I have the following df:

| subject_id | name | day | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sld | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | sld | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | sld | 2 | 12 |
| 1 | dsld | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | dsld | 1 | -1 |
| 2 | sld | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | sld | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | sld | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | sld | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | dsld | 0 | 0 |

I want to make a line plot with the following criteria:

1. Group by `subject_id`
2. for each group, only take the rows where `name == sld`
3. line plot the data where `x` is the `day`, and `y` is the `value`

I want to plot all the groups on the same plot. Preferably using seaborn

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
df_sld = df[df['name'] == 'sld']
df_sld.groupby('subject_id').plot(x = 'day', y = 'value', ax = ax)
```

However, this is taking a long time. Is there a faster way to group by `subject_id` and then only take the rows where `name == sld`

I also tried

```
df.groupby('subject_id')['name'].apply(lambda x: x == 'sld').plot(x = 'day', y = 'value')
df.groupby('subject_id').apply(lambda x: x['name'] == 'sld').plot(x = 'day', y = 'value')
```

But get an error saying no numerical data

Comment: `ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_sld, x='day', y='value', hue='subject_id')` and make sure the `dtype` of each column is correct. Use `df.info()`

Comment: Is there anyway to do it from the `df` directly? without having to first filter by name `df_sld = df[df['name'] == 'sld']`

Comment: Since you want only one of the values in the `'name'` column, `df` must first be filtered.

Comment: It shrinks the dataframe for less processing.  Filter the dataframe first then plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df.query('name == "sld"').set_index(['day', 'subject_id'])['value'].unstack().plot()
```

Output:

[image]